# how do I define c style code blocks in lua?

Tags: c, lua, macros, block

is there a way to define {} and blankspace as a lua code block?

something like this..

```
function()
{
   local x = 3
   if     (x == 1) { print("hi1") }
   elseif (x == 2)   print("hi2") 
   else   (x == 3)   print("hi3") 
}
```

it would also be nice to define things like ++ and += too

Comment: There exist a lot of languages with almost-C syntax.  But in Lua `--` means "start of a single-line comment", and `{..}` is used for a table constructor.

Comment: If you want to experiment with alternative syntax for Lua, try [ltokenp](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#ltokenp).

Comment: I believe the answer to another question explains why lua does not have `+=` well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091779/lua-operators-why-isnt-and-so-on-defined?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Just use `do..end`. `+=` operator and friends aren't conformant with spirit of Lua. Your code will **not** run. First of all, you need to understand basic Lua syntax. Example of corrected code:

```
function f()
   local x = 3
   if x == 1 then
      print("hi1")
   elseif x == 2 then
      print("hi2")
   elseif x == 3 then
      print("hi3")
   end
end
```

To create block simply use

```
do
  print('Hello, world!')
end
```

You can check out Lua manual [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/1.html), whenever you run to trouble.

Comment: I wanted to use some sort of macros to make it look more like c i know there are a few macro libraries that can achieve += and {} i just don't know how to use them.